# PHP how to delete this from a string?

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I want to delete this from a string:

```
[QUOTE=*] * [/QUOTE]

.* kan be anything
```

Can anyone please provide a pattern that I can use?

Comment: I need to use the text after that quoted stuff

Comment: which part do you need to use? the first * or the second one?

Comment: I hope you know that BBCode is not a regular language and thus cannot be parsed with regular expression.

Comment: I need the part after [/QUOTE] and that seems to work unless there's a <br /> inside de quote tags. Then it doesn;t recognize it as the same pattern...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\[QUOTE=[^\]]*\].*\[\/QUOTE\]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: seems to work unless there's a <br /> inside de quote tags. Then it doesn;t recognize it as the same pattern

Comment: It should work with <br />, but it will not match if newlines (\n) are present.

add the 's' modifier to the end (after the final '/') to let it match over newlines. However, you might have to also make the ".*" ungreedy by adding a '?' after it.

Comment: not sure (yet) what an s modifier is, but it worked :) thnx again

Answer (score 2):

Jhongs answer is perfect, it will leave you with the content from the both *'s.

However, if you need the parts separately you can make a small adjustment and add capturing groups like so:

```
if (preg_match('%\[QUOTE=([^\]]*)\](.*)\[/QUOTE\]%', $subject, $matches))
{
...
}
```

The *'s will be at $matches[1] and $matches[2].